# Plot a specific node and its direct neighbors in R Studio

Tags: r, rstudio

I was using the igraph library and I used the neighbors function, but that only gave me a list of all the edges that a particular node had. It doesn't actually plot that graph out.

Is there an easy way to do this? I will post snippets of my code if you need it.

Answer (score 1):

You do not provide any data so I am using a simple example from
[Katya Ognyanova](http://kateto.net/networks-r-igraph). Here is the original data:

```
library(igraph)
gl <- graph_from_literal(a-b-c-d-e-f, a-g-h-b, h-e:f:i, j)
plot(gl)
```

[image: Full Graph]

The node labeled "b" is node 2. To get its neighbors and plot the sub-graph, you can use:

```
VList = c(2, neighbors(gl, 2))
Sgl = induced_subgraph(gl, VList)
plot(Sgl)
```

[image: SubGraph]